# Html.Routelink, Html.BeginRouteForm, Ajax.RouteLink and Ajax.BeginRouteForm not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

`RouteLink` and `BeginRouteForm` gives empty href. If I try to remove any of the custom routes defined in my code, it gives a compilation error. I tried looking for answers in similar questions but none of them works.

My routes contain optional parameters like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute("CustomRoute", "Double/Steps/Add/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "DoubleDodge", action = "Step" });
```

This is how I am calling the route:

```
<div>
    @Ajax.RouteLink("Dodge Me", "CustomRoute", new { id = ViewBag.Id }, new AjaxOptions { AllowCache = false, UpdateTargetId = "main-content-div", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
</div>
```

Looking forward for your response. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Routelink`, you will get a empty href if MVC cannot resolve your route as specified.

I'm betting that your CustomRoute is below your Default route config.  Make sure that any specialized routes are at the top so MVC matches those first, as it will return the 1st match.  And MVC is probably looking for a "Double" controller, "Steps" action, and an "Add" id value.

If that's not the case, then the same issue could happen if your `ViewBag.Id` doesn't contain a value, especially since your "id" isn't optional in your route.  You could make that optional by adding `UrlParameter.Optional` like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CustomRoute",
    url: "Double/Steps/Add/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "DoubleDodge", action = "Step", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And I assume your Controller/Action looks like this:

```
public class DoubleDodge : Controller
{
    public JsonResult Step(string id)
    {
        // create result
        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        return Json(vm);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, default route is at the bottom. If i remove `{id}` from `Double/Steps/Add/{id}`, the route is resolved and I am getting `<a href="Double/Steps/Add"/>`.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I'm betting your "id" isn't populated which is causing the route to not resolve, especially since it's not supposed to be optional.

Comment: Thank you. But `ViewBag.Id` does contain a value when I am debugging it.

Comment: What is that value?  And what is the input parameter type?